# Запрет нажатия кнопки

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте,подскажите пожалуйста.Игра на Win Forms.Пользователь должен ввести свое имя, если имя уже есть в базе данных(т.е. ранее был такой игрок), то кнопка "Готово",которую необходимо нажать после ввода Никнейма не доступна.Пробовал сделать через TextBox,не работает.Подскажите,что исправить.Ниже код.

```
 private void CreateNewPlayer_Window_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Menu_Window Menu_Form = new Menu_Window();
         if (Menu_Form.Players.Exists(x => x.PlayerName == NewPlayerName_TextBox.Text)||NewPlayerName_TextBox.Text=="")
        {
            Ready_Button.Enabled = false;
        }
        else Ready_Button.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: а вы уверены, что у Вас правильно работает поиск игроков? Скорее всего у Вас if всегда = false, вы уверены в корректности Exists?

Comment: @Aleksandr Ter Да даже дело не в Exists,вещи такого вида тоже не работают: 
      `{
            if (NewPlayerName_TextBox.Text == "123") Ready_Button.Enabled = false;
            else Ready_Button.Enabled = true;
        }`

Comment: Программа выполняется в одном потоке?

Comment: @ Aleksandr Ter Все я разобрался,спасибо,действительно там проблема с if"ом была.Спасибо)